# Confused about java -version

Tags: shell, command-line, java, utilities, syntax

For every program/utility on Unix, I would type the name of the program followed by --version to check its version, like so

```
program --version
```

If I understand correctly, the double dash -- is used to specify a single option named version instead of -version, which would mean 7 options v,e,r,s,i,o,n.
Why is it then that for java and javac I have to use -version with a single dash. Java --version does not even work.
Can someone please explain this to me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue is that **every application implements its own argument parsing.** From there it follows that each person/organisation *might* standardise on a format, but you can't convince everyone to follow a single standard.

There are several pieces of historical baggage which make the situation worse:

- The BSD tools and POSIX generally only support the compact `-v` format.
- GNU tools have expanded on POSIX to also support the human-readable `--version` format. They can't support `-version` since it's ambiguous.
- Microsoft standardised on slash as the leading character instead of a hyphen. Since they developed all the core tools for Windows they basically dictated the argument parsing there, which means it's much more uniform.
- Some organisations *only* support human-readable options, so they can use a single hyphen as the prefix to save typing.

Comment: And Java specifically started out (in the 90s and 00s) using the `-char(s)/--word` convention, but in recent years has added lots of `-word` items and discouraged, if not actually deprecated or removed, the `-char` forms. For example `java` in 9 up (but not 8, which OP may have) has both `-version` and `--version` which produce _slightly_ different output, and `-fullversion` but not `--fullversion`.